# Bit array implementation

Tags: c++, array, bitset

I have made a bit array implementation that can be seen below:

```
unsigned int uint_size();

class Bitarray1D {
private:
    unsigned int * array_;
    int elements_;
    int bits_;

public:
    Bitarray1D(int bits);

    ~Bitarray1D();

    void size(int& bits) const;

    unsigned int count() const;

    void setAll(int value);

    void set(int index, int value);

    int test(int index) const;

    unsigned int operator [](int index) const;

    void flip(int index);

    std::string to_string() const;

private:
    void init();

};
```

and some of the functions:

```
void Bitarray1D::init(){
        if (bits_ == 0) throw std::invalid_argument("Can't initialize zero size array");

        int number_of_elements = bits_;
        std::cout << "unsigned int size: " << uint_size() << " bytes" << std::endl;

        elements_ = std::ceil((bits_*1.0)/(uint_size()*1.0));
        array_ = new unsigned int[elements_];
}

int Bitarray1D::test(int index) const {
        if (index < 0 || index >= bits_) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");

        int element = index / uint_size();
        int bit = index % uint_size();

        unsigned int temp_element = array_[element];
        temp_element = temp_element >> bit;

        unsigned int mul = 1;
        temp_element = temp_element & mul;
        return temp_element;
}

unsigned int Bitarray1D::operator [] (int index) const {
        if (index < 0 || index >= bits_) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");

        return test(index);
}
```

`uint_size()` is a function that returns the size of an `unsigned int` in bytes.

While this works well, i want to implement the assignment in array-like style as well, i.e.: `bitarray[i] = 1;`

In the current implementation this is not possible. In order to do so, I figured that `[]` operator in `Bitarray` should return a "Bit object" with the appropriate operators like below:

```
class Bit{
  private:
        unsigned int& element_;
        unsigned int index_;

    int getValue() const{
        // get value of bit
    }
public:
    Bit(unsigned int& element, unsigned int index): element_(element), index_(index){}

    Bit& operator [] (int value){
        return *this;
    }

    Bit& operator = (int value){
          //assign value to the bit
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Bit& bit){
        os << bit.getValue();
        return os;
    }
};
```

This implementation works, but has two major problems:

1. Memory leak. In order for the `[]` operator in `Bitarray` to return a reference to a `Bit` object I have to return the following:

   ```
   Bit& Bitarray1D::operator [] (int index) const {
        return *(new Bit(..., ... ));
   }
   ```
2. I could change the `array_` of the bitarray to hold an array of class `Bit`, but then the whole point of the `Bitarray` is lost, which is smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Don't write a function to return a constant

You don't need `uint_size()`, as the returned value never changes (for a given target platform).  You can replace it with

```
#include <climits>
static const std::size_t uint_bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned int);
```

## Don't require a call to `init()`

The constructor should fully initialize the object; just move the body of `init()` there instead.

## Use integer operations on integers

Instead of using `std::ceil` to round up division, we can do this in integer arithmetic by adding one less than the divisor before dividing:

```
    elements_ = (bits + uint_bits - 1) / uint_bits;
```

Given that we know the number of bits, we can always compute the number of elements when we need it; you might consider the trade-off between storing and computing `elements_`.

## Obey the Rule of Five (or Rule of Zero)

You allocate memory in the constructor, but don't provide copy/move constructors, nor an assignment operator, so you run the risk of double `delete[]`.  The easiest fix is to use a standard container as the storage; you might also consider using a smart pointer to the storage.  As a last resort, you could manage the memory yourself, but I'd advise against that.

## Use an unsigned type for indexing

You can avoid needing to check for negative index values by accepting an unsigned integer type in the methods.  I recommend `std::size_t` as the standard type usually used for that.

## Return by value when possible

```
void size(int& bits) const;
```

is better written as

```
std::size_t size() const;
```

---

## My version

Working replacement code:

```
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

class Bitarray1D {
    using Element = unsigned int;

    class Bit {
        Element& element;
        const Element mask;
    public:
        Bit(Element& element, Element mask) : element{element}, mask{mask} {}
        Bit(const Bit& other) : Bit{other.element, other.mask} {}
        operator bool() const { return element & mask; }
        Bit& operator=(bool b) { element = b ? element | mask : element & ~mask; return *this; }
        Bit& operator=(const Bit& other) { return this->operator=(bool(other)); }
    };

    static const std::size_t element_bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof (Element);

    std::size_t bits;
    std::vector<Element> array;

public:
    Bitarray1D(std::size_t bits);
    ~Bitarray1D() = default;

    std::size_t size() const;

    Bit operator[](std::size_t index);

};

Bitarray1D::Bitarray1D(std::size_t bits)
    : bits{bits},
      array{}
{
    // rounded-up division
    array.resize((bits + element_bits - 1) / element_bits);
}

Bitarray1D::Bit Bitarray1D::operator[](std::size_t index) {
        if (index >= bits)
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
        return Bit(array[index / element_bits], 1u << (index % element_bits));
}


int main()
{
    Bitarray1D bits{15};
    bits[0] = 0;
    bits[2] = bits[1] = 1;
    return bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] != 2;
}
```

Comment: The rule of Five seems the reason why when i declare vector<Bitarray1D> i get all sorts runtime errors. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. You must either delete the move/copy constructors and assignment operators or else define them correctly.

Comment: *"You can avoid needing to check for negative index values by accepting an unsigned integer type in the methods."* That's true, but it just shifts the problem around. Thanks to C++'s awful implicit conversion rules, there's nothing stopping the caller from specifying a negative index value. It will just be implicitly converted to an unsigned value using modulo arithmetic, so what you'll end up with is a very large positive number. So now a bug still lurks, *and worse,* you have no way of ever testing for it! I'd rather just have an assertion that the input is non-negative.

Comment: @Cody - if you have that bug, then the test for `> size()` will catch it (I've just verified this by changing `bits[2]` to `bits[-2]` in the test program).  Are you suggesting that there's a platform on which a negative value will become a valid value when converted?

Comment: Oh, no, sorry. It works fine here. I had missed that the size was a small constant here. I was just noting that using unsigned types to avoid checking for negative inputs is not generally a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

I have a number of comments, so I'll just sort of spray them out.

---

Using a proxy reference type is tricky, and can lead to some interesting problems. For example, a class that provides proxy references (e.g. `vector<bool>` cannot meet the standard's requirements for a container (see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm). It also makes the use of `auto` dangerous:

```
Bitarray1D arr(1);
arr.set(0, 0);
const auto this_isnt_really_a_bool = arr[0];
arr.set(0, 1);
assert(!this_isnt_really_a_bool);  // fails
```

However, if you plan to use a proxy reference, you should return it by *value*, not by reference:

```
Bit Bittarray1D::operator[](int index) const {
    return Bit(array_[element(index)], offset(index)]);
}
```

This solves your memory leak.

---

Why do you use `int` throughout as the type of a bit? What would you do if someone called `set` with `value == 2`? Would you accidentally set the next higher bit (and have undefined behavior if that were already the highest bit in an element)? C++ has a type that takes on the same values as a bit: `bool`.

Likewise, you use multiple types to represent a size (you pass `int` to the constructor and as `bits_` and `elements_` members, you return `unsigned int` from `count`). Use `std::size_t`; it's designed for this purpose.

---

`uint_size` is not such a good idea. Compilers will likely omit optimizations, and experience readers will be confused by the use of a function. Instead, define a constant:

```
constexpr std::size_t uint_size = sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BITS;
```

(some people would name this `kUintSize` or `UINT_SIZE` or similar. In any case, this need not be defined in the header.

By the by, I wouldn't necessarily commit to using `unsigned` as your representation type. If you use a typedef, you can profile to determine which type maximizes performance.

```
using Repr = unsigned;
// using Repr = std::uint64_t;
// using Repr = unsigned char;
```

---

You presumably have the following lines in each member function that takes an `index` argument:

```
    if (index < 0 || index >= bits_) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");

    int element = index / uint_size();
    int bit = index % uint_size();
```

Why not add a couple of private functions that take care of this:

```
std::size_t element(std::size_t index) const {
    if (index >= bits_) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    return index / REPR_BITS;
}
std::size_t offset(std::size_t index) const {
    return index % REPR_BITS;
}
```

---

You keep both `elements_` and `bits_`, but you do not allow users to resize the array, and `elements_` doesn't seem to be used anywhere. Omit `elements_`.

---

Why does `init` exist? You only have one constructor, and even if you added others, you could [delegate](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_delegating_constructors?lang=en).

I've recommended that you eliminate `elements_`, but if you choose not to, please initialize it differently. Using floating point in this way is dangerous. Instead, initialize it like so:

```
elements_ = (bits_ + REPR_BITS - 1) / REPR_BITS;
```

Here's what your constructor should look like.

```
Bitarray1D::Bitarray1D(std::size_t bits) 
    : array_(new Repr[(bits + REPR_BITS - 1) / REPR_BITS]()),
      bits_(bits) {}
```

Note that my code, unlike yours, initializes the array to 0 (`new int[5]()` value-initializes, `new int[5]` does not).

---

Your implementation of `test` has a lot going on; here's a simpler implementation:

```
bool Bitarray1D::test(std::size_t index) const {
    return (array_[element(index)] >> offset(index)) & 1u;
}
```

Comment: You made a lot of good points while I was testing my replacement code (e.g. with a typedef for the element type, and returning the proxy by value).  IF you combine your explanation with my sample code, we're looking good!

Comment: Slight enhancement - your `element()` and `offset()` methods can be `constexpr`, which could help the compiler.

Comment: Both are great answers!